# Get a list from extract used images on a css file using GULP

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want a list of images which is used on a .css file using GULP. I dont have idea how can I do this. Please suggest me or instruct me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written gulp plugin for this work. Check the link : https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=gulp-css-url-extract